# UIPageViewController not displaying UIView

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am implementing Tab control implementation using UISegmentedControl and UIPageViewController. 
The belowmentioned code works perfectly on certain devices and the View corresponding to the clicked segment control gets displayed as expected.

On certain iPhone devices (i think with iOS 11), both the UIViewControllers are not visible at all when I click on the segment control. When I debug the View Hierarchy, I don't see the VC's corresponding to that segment control at all.

But I noticed that the all the delegate methods of the VC like ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear etc get called in each of the VC's when the corresponding segment control is clicked.

What could I be doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class Solution2SegmentControl : UISegmentedControl
{
    private var current:Int = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        current = self.selectedSegmentIndex
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        if current == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
            self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        }
    }
}

class ATSReferralScreensContainer: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    weak var delegateObj:ATSParentViewController?
    @IBOutlet var switchControl: UISegmentedControl!
    var referAFriendVC :ATSReferalScreenVC?
    var referralInformationVC : ATSReferralInfomationVC?

    func setVCForIndex(index: Int) {
        setViewControllers([index == 0 ? referAFriendVC! : referralInformationVC!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }



    func segmentControlClicked(sender: UISegmentedControl)
    {
        setVCForIndex(index: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)

    }


    @IBAction func SegmentControlClick(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        setVCForIndex(index: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self;
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryBoard_ATS", bundle: nil)
        referAFriendVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReferalScreenVC") as! ATSReferalScreenVC

        referralInformationVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReferralInformationVC") as! ATSReferralInfomationVC
        referralInformationVC?.parentDelegateObj = delegateObj

        setVCForIndex(index: 0)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }



    func pageViewController(_ pageView:UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter nextVC:UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        if pageView == referAFriendVC
        {return referralInformationVC } else { return nil }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageView:UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore previousVC:UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        if pageView == referralInformationVC
        { return referAFriendVC } else { return nil }

    }

}
```

Also the belowmentioned code to check if the View is visible **fails** when executed from within the UIViewController implementation.

```
        if self.isViewLoaded && (self.view.window != nil) {
   print("view visible") }
```